# using same class names

Tags: c++, class

I created two different header files, each containing a class with same names and each one is included on different cpp files, so the compiler does not complain about redefinition of them

They operate like two different classes, except when they have the same methods, with same name and same arguments, only one of them is called, for example:

```
//on first cpp:
#include "same1.h"
//...
SameName obj(int_value);
obj.ok(int_value);
obj.not_ok();

//on second cpp
#include "same2.h"
//...
SameName obj(float_value);
obj.ok(float_value);
obj.not_ok();
```

on both files, not_ok from same1.h is called, and of course it has not been initialized correctly

I know what the problem is and why this happens, I'm also familiar with Name mangling and that they both have the exact same name when compiled.

I just want to know that is it standard behavior of C++ or is it just how my compiler have implemented that, I mean, should all compilers do the same thing on this situation or not?

I should mention that I'm using gcc 4.7.1 on Debian Linux.

Comment: read about polymorphism and function overloading

Comment: @Gir: I'm not looking for reason of that, I just want to know if this behavior is defined in standard C++ or not

Comment: i was just suggesting how to get a similar behavior without breaking the rules

Comment: @Gir: You are missing the point of the question. This is not a practical "How do I get this thing done" kind question. This a theoretical "How does C++ work" kind of question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a violation of One Definitlion Rule and undefined behavior.

Comment: I know the reason, my question is something else, please read my question again!

Comment: I've read your question again. I don't see that the answer needs to be anything different. What do you think hasn't been said?

Comment: @PLuS: "Undefined behavior" means that the compiler can do anything it wants to do. There are no guarantees of any kind. So the answer to the question "should all compilers do the same thing on this situation or not?" is No. "Undefined behavior" implies that there is no "standard behavior".

Comment: What I'm looking for is what the standard is about this situation and how should a compiler implement such a situation

Comment: @PLuS: The standard says nothing apart from 'undefined behaviour'. I know some people find this hard to believe, and some people think it's a flaw. But it is the way it is. The advantage of allowing so much undefined behaviour is it means compilers and the code they generate can do much less checking and so be more efficient.

Answer (score 3):

The standard says that if you break this particular rule, then you invoke undefined behaviour. So there is no standard behaviour for your case. But you can expect it not to work. The compiler is following the standard by doing something, because "something" is part of "undefined behaviour".

Comment: So why doesn't compiler complain about that?

Comment: @PLuS because it is allowed to do whatever it wants. It could complain, which would be nice, I agree.

Comment: Because not complaining is also part of undefined behaviour. There are things that the standard says compilers must complain about if they detect them. This isn't one of them.

Comment: @PLuS the standard also allows the compilers to complain about things that are correct but could be wrong. There's even an "effective C++" flag in g++.

Comment: @juanchopanza: even with -Weffc++ compiler does not complain anything!

Comment: @PLuS I only meant to say that the compiler is allowed to complain about some "correct" code, and ignore other clearly incorrect code. You just have to learn what kind of code produces undefined behaviour according to the standard, then you know anything could happen (including programs apparently "working")

Answer (score 2):

By including two different definitions of the same class in your program you are breaking the rules of C++. Therefore the behaviour of your program is undefined.